# Divide and Conquer in big O notation

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I've got a problem – divide-and-conquer part of my program divided my problem into 2 parts: 1/7 and 5/7 of a problem + merging in a linear time. I need to know it's asymptotic complexity. I know, it can be rewritten to $T(n) = T(n/7) + T(5n/7) + O(n)$. Is there a simple way for rewriting this whole thing into big O notation? (Also if you can explain your procedure to me, so I can start using Big O notation on my own, I will be happy!)

Comment: You should read about the "Master theorem": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [Akra–Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), we have:

$$T(n) = T(n/7)+T(5n/7)+g(n)$$
$$a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, b_1 = 1/7, b_2 = 5/7$$
We must find $p$ such that:
$$\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^p+\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^p=1$$
Since $p<2$ in this case, then the Akra–Bazzi method gives you that:
$$T(n) = \Theta(n^{p}(1+n^{1-p}))=\Theta(n)$$

Comment: If $T(n) = \cdots+\cdots+O(n)$ then I do not see how you can conclude $T(n)$ can be smaller than $O(n^1)$

Comment: @Henry - see revised, I forgot a factor in the theorem.

Comment: Pretty cool idea! $p \approx 0,76$

Comment: How do you solve for p $$\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^p+\left(\frac{5}{7}\right)^p=1$$ ?

Comment: @SyedSouban - You don't need to. As long as the $p<1$, then the result will be $O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

The suspicion must be that $T(n) \in O(n)$.

Suppose that you actually have $$T(n) \le  T(n/7) + T(5n/7) + cn$$ for some $c$. Then following the recursion down you have 
$$ T(n) \le c  n  \left(1 + (6/7) + (6/7)^2 + \cdots \right) = 7cn $$ and thus $T(n)\in O(n)$.

Comment: This is essentially the same argument as that a [median of medians algorithm is $O(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Proof_of_O.28n.29_running_time)

Comment: This should really be accepted..